# Django query: Another count question

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

Hello I seem to be having some problem involving counting in Django. I have a list of items which *only* displays its latest status. All of these items that has a status "Destroyed" have been removed. This prints nicely.

```
  status_items = models.StorageItem.objects.filter(client=client_id, itemstatushistory__isnull=False).distinct()

{% for item in status_items %}
        {{item.itemstatushistory_set.latest|cut:"Destroyed"}}
{% endfor %}
```

But I can't count for some reason.

```
  status_items = models.StorageItem.objects.filter(client=client_id, itemstatushistory__isnull=False).distinct().count()
```

`TypeError while rendering: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: by the way, you should accept more answers if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after

```
status_items = models.StorageItem.objects
                     .filter(client=client_id, itemstatushistory__isnull=False)
                     .distinct().count()
```

`status_items` will contain the count of items --> an `int`object

using it in the template in `{% for item in status_items %}` will obviously generate an error.

you can leave it without the `count()` and in the template access to the count like this:

```
{{ status_items.count }}
```

The template system will call `status_items.count()` for you. More infos here: [rendering-a-context](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context)

### EDIT:

> **@Shehzad009** *: What I am trying to achieve, is to
>   count all items that has their latest
>   status not destroyed. Because of the
>   one to many relationship, and because
>   I want to count the latest statuses
>   for each item only, it is a bit tricky*

you could define `status_items` like this:

```
#storageItems where itemstatushistory__status != 'Destroyed'
storage_items = models.StorageItem.objects
                .filter(client=client_id,
                        itemstatushistory__isnull=False
                        )
                .distinct()

# list of items with latest status != 'Destroyed'
status_items = [item for item in storage_items 
                if item.itemstatushistory_set.latest().description !='Destroyed']

# list of items with latest status not in ['Destroyed', 'Out']
status_items = [item for item in storage_items
                if item.itemstatushistory_set.latest().description
                   not in ['Destroyed', 'Out']]
```

then in the template:

```
{# show items with latest status != destroyed  #}
{% for item in status_items %}
        {{ item }}
{% endfor %}

{# items with latest status != destroyed count #}
{{ status_items|length }}
```

Comment: Oh, I have considered this method before, but the problem is that this will be counting all item that has a latest status. Example: If I say I wanted to filter out all latest status destroyed items, I could say this `status_items = models.StorageItem.objects.filter(client=client_id, itemstatushistory__status__description='Destroyed').distinct()
` but there is a problem. If the status for an item is no longer destroyed, it will still be included in the list.

Comment: Take a look at my edit, I may be understood what you're trying to do.

Comment: @manji hmm, got a `non-keyword arg after keyword arg` from where you defined storage_items

Comment: I Fixed that.The reason is that I didn't repect this rule: `Q objects` must precede keyword arguments in lookup functions.

Comment: @Manji almost there - Firstly my program was complaining that there was 'StorageItem object has no attribute  latest'. I removed latest. I  can see what is has done. From each item has many statuses. EX. item1 = {in, out, collected}, item2 ={in, destroyed}, item3 ={collected, destroyed, in} etc. What your answer from your code will give me {item1}. But it want the *latest status* for all items so the answer it needs to be is {item1, item.3}

Comment: @manji Do you really need to load all itemstatushistory for each status_item just to count them?

Comment: @Manji Sorry, it does not filter. Just gives me all entries which have a latest status.

Comment: @Shehzad009, ok there is a missing `()` in my code here: `if item.itemstatushistory_set.latest().description != 'Destroyed'` (`latest` function).

Comment: @Manji Some good news. putting `if item.itemstatushistory_set.latest().status.description != 'Destroyed']` will make it print properly, so printing is fine :). BUT counting does not want to work :(. When I put `{{ status_items.count }}` in my template. Nothing appears. I then tried to put the count() function in the view. But i get `<built-in method count of list object at 0x22c427ec>`. Any ideas?
`

Comment: yes, sorry about that. Try with `{{ status_items|length }}` (`status_items` is now a list, no longer a `QuerySet`)

Comment: Ok yes it has worked at last. One final question. Is it possible from your storage_items definition to make multiple queries. Suppose you instead you wanted to count all statusA and statusB together. Would you be able to count theme both together?

Comment: It's not clear what you need. Do you want items with `statusA and StatusB` or `statusA or statusB` and are you always referring to `latest status`? Can you give an example input->output?

Comment: From your storage item we looked at all latest status dates that are not `Destroyed`. What if we say we _also_  don't want all items that has a latest status of 'Out'. in other words `Destroyed & Out`

Comment: `status_items = [item for item in storage_items if item.itemstatushistory_set.latest().description not in ['Destroyed', 'Out']]`

Answer (score 0):

```
status_items = models.StorageItem.objects.filter(client=client_id, itemstatushistory__isnull=False).distinct().count()
{% for item in status_items %}
        {{item.itemstatushistory_set.latest|cut:"Destroyed"}}
{% endfor %}
```

You've set `status_items` to an integer, so you can't then do `for item in status_items`.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve, is to count all items that has their _latest status_ not destroyed. Because of the one to many relationship, and because I want to count the latest statuses for each item only, it is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Django are you on?

Maybe you could consider using the annotate syntax like described here under Aggregations and other QuerySet clauses:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregations-and-other-queryset-clauses